# Accessing Js variable in php on the same page just with a difference of div tag in URL

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a page say abc.php which displays a list of image names in a table.
When u click on any image name, the page loads an overlay at abc.php#openModal. This new page displays a list of related sensor values which are dependent upon the image name.

How do i get the image name when u click on the link to open the overlay ??

Sample Code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Image name</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href='#openModal'>Image1</a></td></tr>
  </table>
  <div id="openModal">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Sensor value</td></tr>
        <?php
           $sql="SELECT sensor_value FROM table WHERE imageid='$id'";
           $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
           if($result){
             $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
             echo "<tr><td>".$row['sensor_value']."</td></tr>";
           }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: you can load it using ajax on click event

Comment: you have used `ajax` and `xmlhttprequest` as tags for the question but have not detailed any javascript code - I would suggest that ajax is the way forward

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access JS variables from PHP code just because PHP is executed on server and JS - on client. In other words, PHP code ends execution earlier than JS code starts.

In you case you should on click call your JS function, which makes async query to server and displays call result in your modal window.

Comment: I have tried, and failed. Could you write the code snippet?